# Why will my object not follow the curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Sorry, I am a bit of a newbie, so please bear with me, here... I am not going to be good at explaining this. I'll try my best to give more detail if needed.

I am trying to apply the curve modifier to an object. However, even though I set the object and curve's origins to be the same, it still does not slide along the curve or even deform in any way. Instead, when I set the curve object, the mesh moves far away from the curve and just flips according to the axis I choose. If I drag the object, nothing happens, either.

Here is a visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z64l0.jpg

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried following multiple tutorials and fiddling for hours, but I can't figure it out.

If there is alternative way you would suggest doing this, please let me know. I need this to follow the exact curve (the curve was made from the edge of another object that it will fit to).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I find that I have less trouble with curve modifiers when I keep everything at the worldspace origin before creating them.

Comment: A large thing to remember when using a curve modifier is that the curve and the object following the curve have the same origin point. Do whatever you need to do to get there  For example, press shift+s and select "cursor to world origin". Then select the curve, shift+s again, but pick "selection to cursor". Do the same thing with the object following the curve.